# pyspark nested columns in a string

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am working with PySpark. I have a `DataFrame` loaded from csv that contains the following schema:

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- date: date (nullable = true)
 |-- users: string (nullable = true)
```

If I show the first two rows it looks like:

```
+---+----------+---------------------------------------------------+
| id|      date|users                                              |
+---+----------+---------------------------------------------------+
|  1|2017-12-03|{"1":["xxx","yyy","zzz"],"2":["aaa","bbb"],"3":[]} |
|  2|2017-12-04|{"1":["uuu","yyy","zzz"],"2":["aaa"],"3":[]}       |
+---+----------+---------------------------------------------------+
```

I would like to create a new `DataFrame` that contains the 'user' string broken out by each element. I would like something similar to

```
id  user_id     user_product
1   1           xxx
1   1           yyy
1   1           zzz
1   2           aaa
1   2           bbb
1   3           <null>
2   1           uuu

etc...
```

I have tried many approaches but can't seem to get it working.
The closest I can get is defining the schema such as the following and creating a new df applying schema using `from_json`:

```py
userSchema = StructType([
    StructField("user_id", StringType()),
    StructField("product_list", StructType([
        StructField("product", StringType())
    ]))
]) 

user_df = in_csv.select('id',from_json(in_csv.users, userSchema).alias("test"))
```

This returns the correct schema:

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- test: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- user_id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- product_list: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- product: string (nullable = true)
```

but when I show any part of the 'test' `struct` it returns `nulls` instead of values e.g.

```py
user_df.select('test.user_id').show()
```

returns test.user_id :

```
+-------+
|user_id|
+-------+
|   null|
|   null|
+-------+
```

Maybe I shouldn't be using the `from_json` as the users string is not pure JSON. Any help as to approach I could take?

Answer (score 1):

The schema should conform to the shape of the data. Unfortunately `from_json` supports only `StructType(...)` or `ArrayType(StructType(...))` which won't be useful here, unless you can guarantee that all records have the same set of key.

Instead, you can use an `UserDefinedFunction`:

```py
import json
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode, udf

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, "2017-12-03", """{"1":["xxx","yyy","zzz"],"2":["aaa","bbb"],"3":[]}"""),
    (2, "2017-12-04", """{"1":["uuu","yyy","zzz"],"2":["aaa"],"3":[]}""")],
    ("id", "date", "users")
)


@udf("map<string, array<string>>")
def parse(s):
    try:
        return json.loads(s)
    except:
        pass

(df
     .select("id", "date", 
             explode(parse("users")).alias("user_id", "user_product"))
     .withColumn("user_product", explode("user_product"))
     .show())
# +---+----------+-------+------------+
# | id|      date|user_id|user_product|
# +---+----------+-------+------------+
# |  1|2017-12-03|      1|         xxx|
# |  1|2017-12-03|      1|         yyy|
# |  1|2017-12-03|      1|         zzz|
# |  1|2017-12-03|      2|         aaa|
# |  1|2017-12-03|      2|         bbb|
# |  2|2017-12-04|      1|         uuu|
# |  2|2017-12-04|      1|         yyy|
# |  2|2017-12-04|      1|         zzz|
# |  2|2017-12-04|      2|         aaa|
# +---+----------+-------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use `from_json`. You have to `explode` two times, one for `user_id` and one for `users`.

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = sql.createDataFrame([
        (1,'2017-12-03',{"1":["xxx","yyy","zzz"],"2":["aaa","bbb"],"3":[]} ),   
        (2,'2017-12-04',{"1":["uuu","yyy","zzz"],"2":["aaa"],      "3":[]} )],
        ['id','date','users']
    )

df = df.select('id','date',F.explode('users').alias('user_id','users'))\
       .select('id','date','user_id',F.explode('users').alias('users'))

df.show()

+---+----------+-------+-----+
| id|      date|user_id|users|
+---+----------+-------+-----+
|  1|2017-12-03|      1|  xxx|
|  1|2017-12-03|      1|  yyy|
|  1|2017-12-03|      1|  zzz|
|  1|2017-12-03|      2|  aaa|
|  1|2017-12-03|      2|  bbb|
|  2|2017-12-04|      1|  uuu|
|  2|2017-12-04|      1|  yyy|
|  2|2017-12-04|      1|  zzz|
|  2|2017-12-04|      2|  aaa|
+---+----------+-------+-----+
```